# Selenium Cannot Locate a Class

Tags: python, selenium, html-parsing

So l have a problem with locating class while using selenium, I have tried everything l could indeed to successfully locate the class attribute and perform something with it, such as:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div button')
```

```
driver.web.find_element_by_class_name('btn-secondary-md save-button ng-binding')
```

Code Sample:

```
<button class="btn-secondary-md save-button ng-binding" ng-click="$ctrl.showChangeOwnerModal()" ng-bind="'Label.ChangeOwner' | translate">Change Owner</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate by css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn-secondary-md.save-button.ng-binding')
```

If you still get some error like element not clickable, try using explicit waits on the webelement.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are facing issue due to synchronization , you can always use WebDriverWait to avoid synchronization issue.

**solution 1 :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-secondary-md save-button ng-binding")))
```

**solution 2:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Change Owner')]")))
```

**Note :**  Please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

If you still facing issue then please check your element is in iframe, if so then you have to switch control to iframe.